Help me understand Harsanyi's purification theorem
I'm trying to find a game that cannot be purified. Here's an examle from Game Theory by Fudenberg & Tirole:
Consider a $2\times 2$ game:

There are 2 PSNE: $(U,L)\;\&\;(D,R)$. However, $(D,R)$ is not approachable by any equilibrium once the game is perturbed. For instance, suppose that the random variables $\theta_1^{UR}$ and $\theta_1^{DR}$ are symmetrically (e.g. uniformly) distributed on $[-1,1]$. Then, for any probability that player 2 plays $R$, the probability that player 1 strictly prefers to play $U$ is at least $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, player 1's strategy in the perturbed game cannot converge to probability 1 on $D$. Thus, $(D,R)$ cannot be a limit of equilibria of the perturbed game.
Can someone please help me understand why the probability that player 1 strictly prefers to play $U$ is at least 0.5?
